# Declaring multiple types variables inside the init-expression of for statement

Tags: c, declaration

In more complicated `for loops`, I use to declare more that one variable inside the `for`, if they are used for iterating, something like:

```
for (int i = 0, j = size; i < j; ++i, --j)
```

Up until recently I thought it is a `for` syntax, but now I know that `int i = 0, j = size` is seen as one declaration, and `++i, ++j` is seen as two expressions separated by the `comma operator`. So that means that I can declare only one type of variable in the `init-expression` of the for.

How do I declare inside a `for statement` variables of more types, something like:

```
for (int i = 0, auto it = v.begin(); ..; ..)
```

I know I can just declare the variables outside of `for`. And these examples are something that I came up with just now, so maybe they don't make sense, but I encountered real examples where it seemed logic for me to declare more variables inside the `for statement`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; Still the variables have the same type ,i.e, `loopy`.

Comment: The comma in your declaration statement is not doing what you think it is, and certainly not what it does in the increment-statement. The former separates ids of the same type. Think of it as equally invalid to do this *outside* of a for-loop context: `int a=0, long x=1;`

Comment: @WhozCraig I know, I even said that myself in the question. I wanted to know if there is a way to do declare variables of different types.

Comment: @bolov Ah.. `struct` is about the only way I see it without a ton of trickery.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. A simple rule is that, a `for` loop may declare more than one variable, provided that **all variables have the same type**.

Comment: This is sad. [comment padding]

Comment: This is called language limitations :)

Comment: @haccks Is that a C standard reference?  Please supply the section if so.

Comment: @FiddlingBits; Standard doesn't syas much about this. But there is a footnote which only mentions about declaring more than one variable; 6.8.5.3: `158) Thus, clause-1 specifies initialization for the loop, possibly declaring one or more variables for use in
the loop;`. But as @WhozCarig said in his comment that you can't declare variables like `int a, char ch;`, this is syntactically wrong because `,` here is not the *comma operator*.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually. See the following example :

```
for(int i=0,j=1;i<=5,j<=5;i++,j++)
```

as i and j are separated by comma in the conditional statement, as j is incremented latter than i, as soon as j meets its condition i.e. reaching to the count 5, this loop will terminate. Hence, you need to take care of the condition of the second variable.

Comment: The OP knows they can declare 2 variables of the same type in a for loop. Their question is about declaring 2 variables of different types which, as @hackks says, is not possible.

Comment: i <= 5 has no effect.